# Xcode 11: _XCTestCaseInterruptionException when using XCUIElement waitForExistence

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcode11, xcuitest

I'm currently using the standard XCUIElement function waitForExistence(timeout: TimeInterval) in order to wait for a button to show up. I've always set the timeout greater than 2.0 second, but keep running into the same problem.

> Assertion Failure: Failed to get matching snapshots: Unable to perform work on main run loop, process main thread busy for 2.0s - recommend retry by client
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '_XCTestCaseInterruptionException', reason: 'Interrupting test'

It's so frustrating, as this started occurring on Xcode 11 and above. Worse yet, you can't catch the exception, as the waitForExistence method is set to never throw an exception. Any ideas on how to catch this? The element being targeted is simply XCUIApplication().buttons["id"], so it should be good for go. While the app is retrieving data, there shouldn't be any disconnect from the main thread.

Comment: Sadly, it looks like adding a sleep counter helped. I'd still would really avoid using hardcoded sleeps. Still leaving this question open.

Comment: I have such issue with UI tests on Travis CI. It seems like a performance issue. Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a custom wait in the UI tests which always worked (I created an extension for XCTestCase):

```
public class var defaultTimeOut: TimeInterval { return 5 }

public func wait(forFulfillmentOf predicate: NSPredicate,
                 for element: XCUIElement,
                 withFailingMessage message: String = "Failed to fulfill predicate %@ for %@ within %.2f seconds.",
                 timeout: TimeInterval = XCTestCase.defaultTimeOut,
                 file: StaticString = #file,
                 line: UInt = #line) {

    expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)

    waitForExpectations(timeout: timeout) { (error) -> Void in
        guard error != nil else {
            return
        }
        let failingMessage = String(format: message, arguments: [predicate, element, timeout])
        self.recordFailure(withDescription: failingMessage, inFile: String(describing: file), atLine: Int(clamping: line), expected: true)
    }
}
```

Then you can actually use this method inside the UI tests:

```
public func wait(forExistanceOf element: XCUIElement, timeout: TimeInterval = XCTestCase.defaultTimeOut, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    let existancePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    wait(forFulfillmentOf: existancePredicate, for: element, withFailingMessage: "Failed to find %2$@ within %3$.2f seconds. Predicate was: %1$@.", timeout: timeout, file: file, line: line)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question though... were you experiencing the same issue as they were first before you implemented this?

Comment: This example is not complete. If you think this will solve the problem, please add missing functions as expectation, waitForExpectations and recordFailure.